# Copy files from Sharepoint 2007 to USB Hard drive

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, download

I've got this old Sharepoint 2007 sites which contains a lot of projects and files. And I'm looking for a way to copy the entire thing onto an external USB hard drive.

Now, I know I can browse to each project and select "Open with windows explorer" and that gives me an explorer view of the contents. However, what I want to do is to go up a folder and see every project. If I do that, it looks empty. Like there is no content there.

So, is this possible? Or do I have to manually open each project and select "Open with Windows Explorer" for each project?

Comment: How are your projects organized?

Comment: They're organized in a way that each project has it's own "site" so to speak. With it's own content. Filepath-wize, it's like 'sharepoint.domain.com/proj/0002389' or 'sharepoint.domain.com/proj/0002671'. When I open one of these, I can select 'Documents' and 'Open in Windows Explorer'. Is this the information you asked for?

Comment: Are we talking about one document library or several?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a backup of the site collection (`stsadm -o backup`) if it's just for backup purpose (and no other consumption than restoring it on another similar environment) or if it's for consumption outside of a SharePoint environment (hence the usb drive), I would recommend using a (portable & free) tool like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com) which will be able to keep an html copy of all theses sites.